# In an agentless SNMP device, at what level does the SNMP agent run? In the Hardware? In the Operating system? Or somewhere else?

Tags: switch, router, protocol-theory, snmp, management

I know that there are devices that now support agentless SNMP configuration. However I believe that the SNMP agent application has to run somewhere. It has to be some code running somewhere stored on some flash memory or a similar device.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no definitive rule but most likely the agent runs in software on the CPU with code in firmware.

Comment: Regardin personal computers, do operating systems have SNMP agents integrated inside? Or do motherborads firmware have them?

Comment: @yoyo_fun, personal computers and their OSes are off-topic here. You can ask about those on [su].